# Is need to install Cryatal Report in each Client Systems?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to .net Programming.

I want to know the Best Reporting Services.

If I use crystal report, is it install the full crystal report in each client side Systems?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have doubt. Try RDLC report which Visual Studio In build. I am a RDLC report User, Its very simple and not need to install any extra exe's.

Comment: Thanks, What about Crytal Report?.

Comment: Crytal Report is a third party tool but its also integrated in VS. that you want install the SAP Reports exe in Designers Systems.

Answer (score 0):

1) welcome to .NET, we lied about the cake

2) best depends on what you want to do but crystal works very well (I don't get to play with other reporting systems so can't comment really) and it exports to a lot of useful formats.

3) no, there is a crystal reports redistributable that contains just the dlls required by the program to display reports for machines where users do not need to create their own reports.